# Not appropriate position of numbers in confusion matrix Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have code like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(y_test, predictions, rownames=["Observed"], colnames=["Anticipated"])
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True, fmt= "d")
plt.show()
```

Nevertheless, the numbers inside each square are not in the central of each square, as can you see below. How can I change this code so as to have numbers in central position of each square? 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not replicate your issue. I'm getting the numbers centered with your code on Windows 10 Python 3.7. Can you share the versions of python, pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn that you're using?

Comment: I have Python 3.8, Pandas 0.25.1, Mtplotlib 3.1.1 and Seaborn 0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this post on datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57245/seaborn-heatmap-not-displaying-correctly), matplotlib 3.1.1 broke `sns.heatmap()`. The answer there suggests downgrading to matplotlib 3.1.0. But I have installed 3.1.2 on my machine and it is working. So you might be able to upgrade instead now.

```
y_test = np.array(
    [
        "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
        "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar",
        "foo", "foo", "foo"
    ], dtype=object
)
predictions = np.array(
    [
        "one", "one", "one", "two",
        "one", "one", "one", "two",
        "two", "two", "one"
    ], dtype=object
)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(
    y_test, predictions, rownames=["Observed"], colnames=["Anticipated"]
)
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here's the result of `pip list` with the relevant packages.

```
Package            Version   Location
------------------ --------- -------------------------------------
matplotlib         3.1.2
pandas             0.25.1
seaborn            0.9.0
```

Comment: Nevertheless I have a problem when I try to upgrade matplotlin in Anaconda Prompt because I have ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Permission denied: path to my anaconda3

Comment: I was having the same issue when I was trying to upgrade matplotlib. I'd suggest closing out of as much stuff as possible then trying again. I realized I had a figure still open and that was preventing the dll lock to release.